# Jest:moduleNameMapper: mocks do not work for imported modules of mapped modules using "moduleNameMapper"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, git-submodules, jestjs, jest-webpack-alias

I use jest with webpack. Webpack is configured to use alias for some imports:

```
alias: {
  shared: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "some-lib/src"),
},
modules: ["app", "node_modules", "some-lib"],
```

`some-lib` is git submodule added to the project.
When I'm trying to mock imported module in jest it doesn't work

```
jest.mock("shared/utils")
import { utilFunc } from "shared/utils"
```

as a result `utilFunc` is unmocked.
Guys, can someone suggest please how to resolve it?

**UPD:** part of jest config from `package.json`

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^api(.*)$": "<rootDir>/some-lib/src$1"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias

*Create aliases to import or require certain modules more easily. For example, to alias a bunch of commonly used src/ folders.*

In other words, alias **only works with imports or requires**, not jest functions.  What webpack does is actually changes the path out at compile time so when your app compiles what the file actually gets changed to is.

```
jest.mock("shared/utils")
import { utilFunc } from "your_current_working_dir/some-lib/src/utils"
```

As you can see, jest is left unchanged, so the path probably does not exist, therefor jest cannot mock it.  What I would recommend is using the webpack define plugin to create a global variable called something like ABSOLUTE_SHARED_PATH.  Add it to your .eslint globals, then use that for jest so the paths match up.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  ABSOLUTE_SHARED_PATH: JSON.stringify(path.resolve(process.cwd(), "some-lib/src")
})
```

The JSON.stringify is necessary to make it a string.  Webpack does a perfect 1 to 1 replacement with define plugin. This will encapsulate your item as a double quoted string.  Try to JSON.stringify a string in the console for more info.  If you don't do this webpack will throw an error.

Now, when you change jest in your code

```
jest.mock(path.resolve(ABSOLUTE_SHARED_PATH, "shared/utils"));
```

It will be transformed to the correct path

Comment: thank you thomas it makes a good sense. as I understand jest has something similar to webpack aliases https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string
I just updated my question to include jest config of this option, apparently, it doesn't seem to be working to me